# access ANKO sqlite DB inside ANKO layout component

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, anko

I want to access my ANKO SQLite database, inside of my `AnkoComponent`. However I get prompted with an error within the scope of the component, and in the activity using the `AnkoComponent` it works just fine.

This is my ANKO SQLite database

```
package com.example.jokegenerator

import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.*

class DatabaseOpenHelper(context: Context) :
        ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper(context, "Database", null, 2) {


    companion object {
        private var instance: DatabaseOpenHelper? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(ctx: Context): DatabaseOpenHelper {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = DatabaseOpenHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext())
            }
            return instance!!
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        // Here you create tables
        db.createTable("Jokes", true,
            "id" to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY + UNIQUE,
            "joke" to TEXT)
        db.insert("Jokes",
            "joke" to "Humor is not for everyone")
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db.dropTable("User", true)
    }
}

val Context.database: DatabaseOpenHelper
    get() = DatabaseOpenHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
```

This is the activity using the ANKO layout component, from where the component should use the database inside of a button. I have Commented inside `AnkoComponent`'s code, to specify.

```
class JokeActivityUI : AnkoComponent<JokeActivity> {

    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<JokeActivity>) = with(ui) {
        verticalLayout {
            textView {

            }.lparams(width = matchParent) {

            }
            var getRndJoke = button {
                text = "get random joke!"


                onClick {
                    database.use{ //prompted with error written below!

                    }


                }
            }.lparams(width = matchParent) {

            }
            button {
                text = "create a joke"
                onClick {
                    startActivity<CreateJokeActivity>()
                }
            }.lparams(width = matchParent) {

            }
            button {
                text = "frontpage"
                onClick {
                    startActivity<MainActivity>()
                }
            }.lparams(width = matchParent) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I am prompted with an error message saying:

> public val Context.database: DatabaseOpenHelper defined in
>   com.example.jokegenerator in file Database.kt

But inside of the activity using the layout I can use the database just fine

```
class JokeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        JokeActivityUI().setContentView(this)


        database.use { //works just fine in this scope
            val dbJokes = database.use {
                select("Jokes")
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not access it from Activity? I think better to keep UI only focus on UI.

First, create lateinit var in JokeActivityUI called getRndJoke

```
class JokeActivityUI : AnkoComponent<JokeActivity> {

     lateinit var getRndJoke: Button

     ...
}
```

Then assign variable getRndJoke to the button

```
getRndJoke = button {
   text = "get random joke!"
}.lparams(width = matchParent)
```

So, you can easily access database in Activity like this:

```
class JokeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        JokeActivityUI().setContentView(this)

        JokeActivityUI().getRndJoke.onClick {

           database.use {
              ...
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Extra: I think better to create instance JokeActivityUI like this:

```
val ui = JokeActivityUI()
```

Comment: thanks for providing a solution not only to the specific question but for improving my architecture as well :)

Comment: About improving architecture or not, I don't know. But I think it's such a good solution.